# Error in logCat with onNestedScrollAccepted

Tags: java, android, android-actionbaractivity

I extend ActionBarActivity in my class and i have this kind of error :

```
 2-27 09:41:59.787    1836-1836/com.application.wineot.wineotapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted

02-27 09:41:59.787    1836-1836/com.application.wineot.wineotapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11481: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V

02-27 09:41:59.787    1836-1836/com.application.wineot.wineotapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000

02-27 09:41:59.787    1836-1836/com.application.wineot.wineotapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll

02-27 09:41:59.787    1836-1836/com.application.wineot.wineotapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11487: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
02-27 09:41:59.787    1836-1836/com.application.wineot.wineotapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000

02-27 09:41:59.787    1836-1836/com.application.wineot.wineotapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled

 02-27 09:41:59.787    1836-1836/com.application.wineot.wineotapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9172: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V

02-27 09:41:59.787    1836-1836/com.application.wineot.wineotapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e

02-27 09:41:59.791    1836-1836/com.application.wineot.wineotapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations

02-27 09:41:59.791    1836-1836/com.application.wineot.wineotapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 455: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I

02-27 09:41:59.791    1836-1836/com.application.wineot.wineotapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002

02-27 09:41:59.791    1836-1836/com.application.wineot.wineotapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType

02-27 09:41:59.791    1836-1836/com.application.wineot.wineotapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 477: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I

02-27 09:41:59.791    1836-1836/com.application.wineot.wineotapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
```

I don't know why this error is here...

I show my code in my class too :

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.application.wineot.wineotapplication.MainActivity;
import com.application.wineot.wineotapplication.R;

import Fonction.CustomToast;
import Fonction.menuListAdapter;
import contactUs.ContactUs;
import myBottles.MyBottles;
import takepicture.TakePictureBottle;
```

public class MyAccount extends ActionBarActivity{

```
//Use for the left menu
String[]                        menu;
DrawerLayout                    dLayout;
ListView                        dList;

//use drawerLayout and drawerToggle to have an animation on the left menu
DrawerLayout                    drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle           drawerToggle;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_account);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        MyAccountFragment fragmentMyAccountFragment = new MyAccountFragment();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_my_account, fragmentMyAccountFragment).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
    //use animation of the left menu
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {};
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    //set menu Left and the activity linked
    menu = new String[]{"My account","Scan a bottle","My bottles","Contact Us","Logout"};
    dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_left);
    this.dList.setAdapter(new menuListAdapter(menu, getResources().getIntArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons_menu_left), getLayoutInflater()));
    dList.setSelector(R.color.bordeaux);
    dList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {

            dLayout.closeDrawers();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("Menu", menu[position]);
            if (menu[position].equals("My account"))
            {
                //Toast is a view containing a quick little message for the user
                new CustomToast(getString(R.string.MyAccountAlreday), getLayoutInflater(), (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout), getApplicationContext());
            }
            if (menu[position].equals("Scan a bottle"))
                startActivity(new Intent(MyAccount.this, TakePictureBottle.class));
            if (menu[position].equals("My bottles"))
                startActivity(new Intent(MyAccount.this, MyBottles.class));
            if (menu[position].equals("Contact Us"))
                startActivity(new Intent(MyAccount.this, ContactUs.class));
            if (menu[position].equals("Logout"))
                startActivity(new Intent(MyAccount.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

If somebody know this error and how resolve this I am here :)

Comment: have you filtered your `logcat` or somehow not posted all of it?

Comment: yes but the error come from for the same error